# How do you get exact path to My Documents using F#

Tags: f#

Is there any way to get `My Documents` path in F#?

I found `Environment.SpecialFolder`, but it looks like it is only used in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "it looks like it is only used in C#". The exact same invocation you'd use in C# actually works in F# as well:

```
open System;

let myDocuments = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
```